invalid use of non-static member function arduino IDE ESP32 Wifi
I am trying to convert my basic library that handles my wifi connection on my fleet of IoT EPS32 to a library that uses a class, to be able to use callbacks and more structured data exchange between multiple libraries.
When moving my "Setup" function into the class i get the following error:
I marked the line 78 and 143 in the code.
In file included from C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Arduino15\RemoteSketchbook\ArduinoCloud\X\ESP32_Waermepumpensteuerung\ESP32_Waermepumpensteuerung.ino:40:
C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Arduino15\RemoteSketchbook\ArduinoCloud\X\ESP32_Waermepumpensteuerung\Wifi_Connection.h: In member function 'void WiFi_Handler::setup()':
C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Arduino15\RemoteSketchbook\ArduinoCloud\X\ESP32_Waermepumpensteuerung\Wifi_Connection.h:78:16: error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void WiFi_Handler::WiFiEvent(arduino_event_id_t)'
   78 |   WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Arduino15\RemoteSketchbook\ArduinoCloud\X\ESP32_Waermepumpensteuerung\Wifi_Connection.h:143:8: note: declared here
  143 |   void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event) {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
  Used: C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\3.0.7\libraries\WiFi
  Not used: C:\Users\X\Documents\Arduino\libraries\WiFiNINA
exit status 1

Compilation error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void WiFi_Handler::WiFiEvent(arduino_event_id_t)'

The following is my library. I tried to reduce it to the necessary only:
//USes standard Wifi and WiFIUDP Lib

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>


const char* ssid = "mySSID";
const char* password = "myPW";
boolean wifi_connected = false;

IPAddress MiniserverIP(192, 168, XXX, XXX);
IPAddress localIP(127, 0, 0, 1);
unsigned int MiniserverPort = XXXX;
unsigned int localPort = XXXX;
IPAddress GatewayIP(192, 168, XXX, XXX);
IPAddress SubnetMask(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress DNS(192, 168, XXX, XXX);


const int UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE = 48;

// buffers for receiving and sending data
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE];

// UDP Packet Flag
int UDP_Packet_received = 0;

boolean UDP_started = false;


WiFiUDP Udp;

unsigned long last_wifi_status_update;



class WiFi_Handler {
public:
  // Typedef für die Callback-Funktion
  typedef void (*CallbackFunction)(String&);

  // Konstruktor
  //WiFi_Handler();

  // Setzt die Callback-Funktion
  void setDebugOutputCallback(CallbackFunction debugOutputCallback) {
    _debugOutputCallback = debugOutputCallback;
  }

  // Führt die Callback-Funktion aus
  void sendDebugOutput(String& arg) {
    if (_debugOutputCallback) {
      _debugOutputCallback(arg);
    }
  }

  // Function to send UDP packets
  void sendUDP(String text) {
    Udp.beginPacket(MiniserverIP, MiniserverPort);
    Udp.print(text);
    Udp.endPacket();
    Serial.print("UDP send: ");
    Serial.println(text);
  }

  void setup() {
  setWifiConfig();

  // delete old config
  WiFi.disconnect(true);

  delay(1000);

  // Examples of different ways to register wifi events
  //THIS IS LINE 78!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);

  //scanAndConnectToStrongestNetwork();

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Wait for WiFi... ");
}


void loop() {

  if (wifi_connected == false) {
    delay(10000);
    if (wifi_connected == false) {
      Wifi_connect();
    }
  }
  if (UDP_started == false & wifi_connected == true) {
    Udp.begin(localPort);
    Serial.println("UDP started");
    UDP_started = true;
  }

  //send_status();
}

private:
  CallbackFunction _debugOutputCallback;  // Zeiger auf die Callback-Funktion

  void send_status() {
    if ((millis() - last_wifi_status_update) > 60000 or last_wifi_status_update > millis()) {
      sendUDP("RSSI:" + String(WiFi.RSSI()));
      Serial.println("RSSI: " + String(WiFi.RSSI()));
      last_wifi_status_update = millis();
    }
  }

  void setWifiConfig() {
    if (host == "ESP32 Toroeffner") {
      IPAddress temp_IP(192, 168, XXX, XXX);
      localIP = temp_IP;
      MiniserverPort = XXXX;
      localPort = XXXX;
    } else if (host == "ESP32_Waermepumpe") {
      IPAddress temp_IP(192, 168, XXX, XXX);
      localIP = temp_IP;
      MiniserverPort = XXXX;
      localPort = XXXX;
    } 
  }

  //This is Line 143!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event) {
    Serial.printf("[WiFi-event] event: %d\n", event);

    switch (event) {
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_READY:
        Serial.println("WiFi interface ready");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_SCAN_DONE:
        Serial.println("Completed scan for access points");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_START:
        Serial.println("WiFi client started");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_STOP:
        Serial.println("WiFi clients stopped");
        wifi_connected = false;
        UDP_started = false;
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_CONNECTED:
        Serial.println("Connected to access point");
        //wifi_connected = true;
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_DISCONNECTED:
        Serial.println("Disconnected from WiFi access point");
        wifi_connected = false;
        UDP_started = false;
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_AUTHMODE_CHANGE:
        Serial.println("Authentication mode of access point has changed");
        wifi_connected = false;
        UDP_started = false;
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_GOT_IP:
        Serial.print("Obtained IP address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        wifi_connected = true;
        sendUDP(Version);
        sendUDP("Wifi Connected");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_LOST_IP:
        Serial.println("Lost IP address and IP address is reset to 0");
        wifi_connected = false;
        UDP_started = false;
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WPS_ER_SUCCESS:
        Serial.println("WiFi Protected Setup (WPS): succeeded in enrollee mode");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WPS_ER_FAILED:
        Serial.println("WiFi Protected Setup (WPS): failed in enrollee mode");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WPS_ER_TIMEOUT:
        Serial.println("WiFi Protected Setup (WPS): timeout in enrollee mode");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WPS_ER_PIN:
        Serial.println("WiFi Protected Setup (WPS): pin code in enrollee mode");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_AP_START:
        Serial.println("WiFi access point started");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_AP_STOP:
        Serial.println("WiFi access point  stopped");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_AP_STACONNECTED:
        Serial.println("Client connected");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_AP_STADISCONNECTED:
        Serial.println("Client disconnected");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_AP_STAIPASSIGNED:
        Serial.println("Assigned IP address to client");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_AP_PROBEREQRECVED:
        Serial.println("Received probe request");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_AP_GOT_IP6:
        Serial.println("AP IPv6 is preferred");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_GOT_IP6:
        Serial.println("STA IPv6 is preferred");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP6:
        Serial.println("Ethernet IPv6 is preferred");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_START:
        Serial.println("Ethernet started");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_STOP:
        Serial.println("Ethernet stopped");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_CONNECTED:
        Serial.println("Ethernet connected");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_DISCONNECTED:
        Serial.println("Ethernet disconnected");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP:
        Serial.println("Obtained IP address");
        break;
      default: break;
    }
  }

  void Wifi_connect() {
    Serial.println("start connecting to Wifi");
    // delete old config
    WiFi.disconnect(true);

    delay(1000);

    if (WiFi.config(localIP, GatewayIP, SubnetMask, DNS, DNS) == false) {
      Serial.println("Configuration failed.");
    }

    //scanAndConnectToStrongestNetwork();

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Wait for WiFi... ");
  }
};


String scanAndConnectToStrongestNetwork() {
  int i_strongest = -1;
  int32_t rssi_strongest = -100;
  Serial.printf("Start scanning for SSID %s\r\n", ssid);

  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();  // WiFi.scanNetworks will return the number of networks found
  Serial.println("Scan done.");

  if (n == 0) {
    Serial.println("No networks found!");
    return ("");
  } else {
    Serial.printf("%d networks found:", n);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
      // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
      Serial.printf("%d: BSSID: %s  %2ddBm, %3d%%  %9s  %s\r\n", i, WiFi.BSSIDstr(i).c_str(), WiFi.RSSI(i), constrain(2 * (WiFi.RSSI(i) + 100), 0, 100), (WiFi.encryptionType(i) == WIFI_AUTH_OPEN) ? "open" : "encrypted", WiFi.SSID(i).c_str());
      if ((String(ssid) == String(WiFi.SSID(i)) && (WiFi.RSSI(i)) > rssi_strongest)) {
        rssi_strongest = WiFi.RSSI(i);
        i_strongest = i;
      }
    }
  }

  if (i_strongest < 0) {
    Serial.printf("No network with SSID %s found!\r\n", ssid);
    return ("");
  }
  Serial.printf("SSID match found at %d. Connecting...\r\n", i_strongest);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password, 0, WiFi.BSSID(i_strongest));
  return (WiFi.BSSIDstr(i_strongest));
}




// Function to send UDP packets
void sendDebug(String text) {
  IPAddress DesktopIP(192, 168, XXX, XXX);
  Udp.beginPacket(DesktopIP, XXXX);
  Udp.print(text);
  Udp.endPacket();
  Serial.print("Debug send: ");
  Serial.println(text);
}


// Function to send UDP packets
  void sendUDP(String text) {
    Udp.beginPacket(MiniserverIP, MiniserverPort);
    Udp.print(text);
    Udp.endPacket();
    Serial.print("UDP send: ");
    Serial.println(text);
  }






// Function to check for new UDP packets
int checkUDP(char* data) {
  // if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    // read the packet into packetBufffer
    Udp.read(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);
    UDP_Packet_received = 1;

    // for debug only
    // write packetBuffer to serial
    Serial.print("UDP Packet received, Packet Content: ");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(packetBuffer); i++) {
      data[i] = packetBuffer[i];
    }

    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}


The name of a free function will decay to a function pointer, a member-function will not. You need &class_name::member_name to get the address, but that is then a "member function pointer", and not the same as a "function pointer".

See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types

Thanks for the answer. So my understanding is, because i want to pass a member function of my class to the underlaying WiFi Class, i cannot do this as it is not existend at compile time, due to my class not being created yet.
Your suggestion with modifieng it like WiFi.onEvent(&WiFi_Handler::WiFiEvent); works as soon as i turn the WiFiEvent function to static, which is no problem for me, as it only decodes the various states

No, the problem is not that class is not created yet. The problem is that non-static member function require an object to be called on. Like beginPacket is a non-static member function and you call it on object named Udp. If compiler allowed what you tried to do, there would be no object to call WiFiEvent on, because how can anyone know what object do you want?
